# windows server 2012 r2 запретить автоматическое завершение пользовательской сессии

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2012

- Заходим по RDP на арендованный виртуальный Windows Server 2012 r2.
- Запускаем программу от имени пользователя.
- Отключаемся от RDP

Через небольшой промежуток времени Windows автоматически завершает сеанс пользователя. Вместе с сеансом завершает и запущенные от имени пользователя программы.

Как заблокировать автоматическое завершение сессии пользователя?

Comment: Вот тут есть ответ: [Disable remote session timeout on Win Server 2012 R2](https://serverfault.com/q/622898/418761)

Comment: Но, вообще-то, надо выбирать программы которым не требуется активная сессия для работы.